# DMARC REPORT HTML READ

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

I need to understand/read a dmarc report to understand as to whether my emails are being sent properly (not to receivers spam) and being received without being ignored/deleted. Any help is appreciated! Thanks, Dan

The report is below.

```
<feedback>
<version>1.0</version>
<report_metadata>
<org_name>zoho.com</org_name>
<email>noreply-dmarc@zoho.com</email>
<extra_contact_info>https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/dmarc-policy.html</extra_contact_info>
<report_id>dd909efb-2609-42e7-97a8-199267b26fc2</report_id>
<date_range>
<begin>1661756400</begin>
<end>1661842800</end>
</date_range>
</report_metadata>
<policy_published>
<domain>flankaudio.com</domain>
<adkim>r</adkim>
<aspf>r</aspf>
<p>none</p>
<pct>100</pct>
<fo>0</fo>
</policy_published>
<record>
<row>
<source_ip>209.85.208.48</source_ip>
<count>1</count>
<policy_evaluated>
<disposition>none</disposition>
<dkim>fail</dkim>
<spf>pass</spf>
</policy_evaluated>
</row>
<identifiers>
<header_from>flankaudio.com</header_from>
</identifiers>
<auth_results>
<dkim>
<result>fail</result>
<domain>flankaudio.com</domain>
<selector>google</selector>
</dkim>
<spf>
<domain>flankaudio.com</domain>
<result>pass</result>
<scope>mfrom</scope>
</spf>
</auth_results>
</record>
</feedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `<policy_evaluated>` block in the XML report. In your case it is:

```xml
<policy_evaluated>
<disposition>none</disposition>
<dkim>fail</dkim>
<spf>pass</spf>
</policy_evaluated>
```

Here's what they mean:

- `<dkim>fail</dkim>` - DKIM failed
- `<spf>pass</spf>` - SPF passed
- `<disposition>none</disposition>` - DMARC passed (meaning: email could be delivered)

Comment: Awesome thank you for your help. By could be delivered, does that mean it was delivered?

Comment: You can't tell that by just looking at a DMARC record. A DMARC _pass_ only indicates that the email is okay as far as the DMARC policy published by the domain owner is concerned. Emails servers may or may not use a DMARC _pass_ as a factor when ranking emails, but this is a local decision, outside of the scope of DMARC.